# How to set Table.Header sticky in React Semantic?

Tags: reactjs

I can't make table header sticky.

I tried to change style like

```
<Table.Header style={{position: 'sticky' ,
            top: 0,
             background :0.0,
              opacity: 1,
            }}>
```

In this case position of header setted normally, but oppacity doesn't set 1. And this solution works not properly as I want.
Also I tried to set tag  in every place.

```
const PhoneAndCosts = () => {

  return isRequestSending ? (
    <Segment
      middle
      aligned
      style={{
        overflow: 'auto',
        height: 400,
      }}
    >
      <Dimmer active inverted>
        <Loader inline="centered" size="large">Search...</Loader>
      </Dimmer>
    </Segment>
  ) : (
    <React.Fragment >
      <Segment
        style={{
          overflow: 'auto',
          height: 400,
        }}
      >
        <Table size="small" striped textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">

            <Table.Header style={{position: 'sticky' ,
            top: 0,
             background :0.0,
              opacity: 1,
            }}>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.HeaderCell width={6}>Number</Table.HeaderCell>
                {radioType
                  && (<Table.HeaderCell width={12}>Cost</Table.HeaderCell>)
                }
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Header>
          <Table.Body>
            {currentState.map(h => (
              <Table.Row active={!h.isSelected} key={h.phone}>
                <Table.Cell>
                  <Checkbox
                    label={h.phone}
                    disabled={h.isDisabled}
                    checked={!h.isSelected}
                    onChange={() => selectShowingNumberState(`${h.phone}`)}
                    radio={radioType}
                  />
                </Table.Cell>
                {radioType && (<Table.Cell>{h.cost}</Table.Cell>)}
              </Table.Row>
            ))}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
      </Segment>
      <NumberPagination
        pageCount={pageCount}
        showPage={showPage}
        aPage={activePage}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css to your css file

```
.ui.table thead {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

Working sandbox [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bhabha-0viju)

It won't work if table is stacked on small screen sizes.
Tested on Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Yes,it's working solution, but we can see background above header. How can i fix it?

Comment: yeah it is due to padding on segment, try this https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-lederberg-o72hg

Comment: change top to `top:-1em;` i.e padding on segment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I do like(maybe it will help somebody).

```
return isRequestSending ? (
    <Segment
      middle
      aligned
      style={{
        overflow: 'auto',
        height: 400,
      }}
    >
      <Dimmer active inverted>
        <Loader inline="centered" size="large">Выполняется поиск номеров</Loader>
      </Dimmer>
    </Segment>
  ) : (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Table
        size="small"
        striped
        textAlign="center"
        verticalAlign="middle"
        style={{
          marginBottom: '-15px',
          borderBottomColor: 'white',
        }}
      >
        <Table.Header
          style={{
            position: 'sticky',
            top: 0,
            background: 0.0,
            opacity: 1,
          }}
        >
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell width={8}>phone number</Table.HeaderCell>
            {radioType
            && (<Table.HeaderCell width={8}>cost</Table.HeaderCell>)
            }
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>
      </Table>
      <Segment
        basic
        style={{
          overflow: 'auto',
          height: 400,
          opacity: 1,
          paddingLeft: '0px',
          paddingRight: '0px',
          marginBottom: '0px',
        }}
      >
        <Table
          basic
          size="small"
          textAlign="center"
          verticalAlign="middle"
          style={{
            marginTop: '-15px',
          }}
        >
          <Table.Body>
            {currentState.map(h => (
              <Table.Row active={!h.isSelected} key={h.phone}>
                <Table.Cell width={8}>
                  <Checkbox
                    label={h.phone}
                    disabled={h.isDisabled}
                    checked={!h.isSelected}
                    onChange={() => selectShowingNumberState(`${h.phone}`)}
                    radio={radioType}
                  />
                </Table.Cell>
                {radioType && (<Table.Cell width={8}>{h.cost}</Table.Cell>)}
              </Table.Row>
            ))}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
      </Segment>
      <NumberPagination
        pageCount={pageCount}
        showPage={showPage}
        aPage={activePage}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```